# how add a form in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I created a views showing user details, and i would like to show this views by date-wise.
I want to create a starting date and ending date (January 1 2011 to February 25 2011),  then click submit. It show only the user join between January 1 to February 25. 
Is it not possible to do in views, if so please tell me the other methods to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the **Filter** area in views. You select the User Join date as a filter, then you click the **Expose** button. Then in the radio list choose the one where it says something like "*is between*". Then you should have a form where you can select a start and end date for the users on the page.

Comment: really thanks zeroFiG, its working fine. i want to know what all options in view module.